# Rails 4.2 + Ember => unexpected identifier

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I'm following  [Vic Ramon's tutorial](http://ember.vicramon.com/hello-world). I tried to use the latest version of Rails and Ember-source and I get the following error when visiting home page:
[image]
After clicking on link next to error I get this:
[image]
How can I fix that?

I ran the following commands:
rails g ember:bootstrap -n App --javascript-engine coffee
rails g ember:install

I removed turbolinks. I also created home controller and an empty view for home#index. Root is set to home#index. Also created following view file:

```
// app/assets/javascripts/templates/application.js.emblem
h1 Hello World
outlet
```

Ember gems im using:

```
Using emblem-source 0.3.18
Using ember-data-source 1.0.0.beta.14.1
Using ember-rails 0.16.1
Using emblem-rails 0.2.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emblem was the culprit. Replacing .emblem with .handlebars fixed the problem. I tried the tip from emblem-rails git page and icluded

```
gem "emblem-source", github: "machty/emblem.js"
```

but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to some version incompatibilities between your versions of ember-related gems, as there were quite substantial changes in recent versions of ember (e.g. introduction of HTMLBars, etc.)

Your best bet is to clone the [original repo](https://github.com/vicramon/ember-hello-world) and then try to upgrade individual gems and check if it still works after each upgrade. This way you will be able to identify the troubling gem.

I have verified that the original repo code indeed works with the versions of gems in its current `Gemfile.lock`.

If you are starting a new Rails + Ember app, [ember-cli-rails](https://github.com/rwz/ember-cli-rails) is probably the way to go, giving you the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 0):

I also followed this tutorial (alongside a few others) and I encountered several issues alongside the way ranging from handling templates to setting up the JSON API. I don't see your entire source code so I cannot pinpoint the exact problem. However, it seems that we have similar projects, so you can compare your code to my blog project source code and see what is causing these issues. Comparing to  [Ramon's tutorial](http://ember.vicramon.com/chapters), my blog has implemented everything until chapter 15.

https://github.com/Deovandski/Fakktion/tree/Ember-Rails

If you are a beginner like myself, then I recommend avoiding CoffeeScript and Emblem and sticking to Javascript as much as possible for the first months because you will find more resources and examples. Also, let me know if you need assistance in setting up the project as I used `.gitignore` to hide things like `secrets.yml`